# Getting "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, openjpa, ibm-rad

I created the small JPA project to persist a Student record. I use Oracle database. I use the OpenJPA as the JPa provider.

I have created the Table student and relevant sequences correctly.

**Student Entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Student() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TRAIN_SEQ", sequenceName = "STUDENT_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TRAIN_SEQ")
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="JPAOracleDemo">

        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

        <class>com.jpa.demo.model.Student</class>

        <properties>
             <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@TEST:50111:TESTPEGAD1" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="admin" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="admin" />
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="MYSCHEMA" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**Client Class**

```
OpenJPAEntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        OpenJPAEntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        // Create the instance of Employee Entity class
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName("A.Ramesh");

        // JPA API to store the Student instance on the database.
        em.persist(student);
        tx.commit();
        em.close();

        System.out.println("Done...");
```

**Util class**

```
private static OpenJPAEntityManagerFactory emf = OpenJPAPersistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("JPAOracleDemo", "META-INF/persistence.xml");

    private static OpenJPAEntityManager entManager;

    /**
     * No need to create any instance for this Util.
     */
    private JPAUtil() {
    }

    /**
     * Get {@link EntityManager}.
     * 
     * @return the {@link EntityManager}
     */
    public static OpenJPAEntityManager getEntityManager() {

        if (entManager == null || !entManager.isOpen()) {
            entManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        }

        return entManager;
    }
```

**The data persist in the student table successfully, but I have the bellow error**

```
Exception in thread "Attachment 60230" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot get the capability, performing dispose of the retransforming environment
    at com.ibm.tools.attach.javaSE.Attachment.loadAgentLibraryImpl(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.tools.attach.javaSE.Attachment.loadAgentLibrary(Attachment.java:253)
    at com.ibm.tools.attach.javaSE.Attachment.parseLoadAgent(Attachment.java:235)
    at com.ibm.tools.attach.javaSE.Attachment.doCommand(Attachment.java:154)
    at com.ibm.tools.attach.javaSE.Attachment.run(Attachment.java:116)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot get the capability, performing dispose of the retransforming environment
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.isRetransformClassesSupported0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.isRetransformClassesSupported(InstrumentationImpl.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ClassRedefiner.canRedefineClasses(ClassRedefiner.java:123)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:122)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:304)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:202)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:45)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at com.jpa.demo.util.JPAUtil.getEntityManager(JPAUtil.java:32)
    at com.jpa.demo.client.JPAClient.main(JPAClient.java:13)
1045  JPAOracleDemo  INFO   [main] openjpa.Enhance - Creating subclass for "[class com.jpa.demo.model.Student]". This means that your application will be less efficient and will consume more memory than it would if you ran the OpenJPA enhancer. Additionally, lazy loading will not be available for one-to-one and many-to-one persistent attributes in types using field access; they will be loaded eagerly instead.
Done...
```

**Java version**

JDK 1.6

Anybody please let me know what is the issue here?

**Updated:**

I used the IBM Rational Software Architect for Websphere Software for this development. this problem is with this IDE. When I create the JPA project by default it adds the IBM jre. I just removed the IBM jre and tried with the SUN jre then it was success. Please let me know why this function does not support with IBM jre?

Comment: Seems like problem is in <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />. Please check at http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_pc_enhance.html#ref_guide_pc_enhance_unenhanced_types and at http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.1/apache-openjpa-1.2.1/docs/javadoc/org/apache/openjpa/conf/OpenJPAConfiguration.html

Answer (score 2):

`<property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />`

For starters, get rid of that property.

Comment: I tried that scenario also but no luck. I got the bellow error. Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.0.0-r422266:935683 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Attempt to cast instance "com.jpa.demo.model.Student@29e029e" to PersistenceCapable failed.  Ensure that it has been enhanced.
FailedObject: com.jpa.demo.model.Student@29e029e

Comment: Enhance your Entities using build time enhancement or via a -javaagent

Comment: Thanks Rick. Can you please guide me to do the build time enhancement?

Answer (score 1):

This is my enhancer template, this works properly for OPENJPA: 
`

```
<path id="enhance.cp">
       <pathelement location="${basedir}${file.separator}${build.dir}" />
        <fileset dir="${basedir}${file.separator}ext_libs/">
          <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
<property name="cp" refid="enhance.cp" />
 <target name="openjpa.libs.check" unless="openjpa.libs">
    <fail message="Please set -Dopenjpa.libs in your builder configuration!" />
 </target>
 <target name="build.dir.check" unless="build.dir">
    <fail message="Please set -Dbuild.dir in your builder configuration!" />
</target>
<target name="enhance" depends="openjpa.libs.check, build.dir.check">
    <echo message="${cp}" />
    <taskdef name="openjpac" classname="org.apache.openjpa.ant.PCEnhancerTask">
        <classpath refid="enhance.cp" />
    </taskdef>
    <openjpac>
        <classpath refid="enhance.cp" />
     <configpropertiesFile="${basedir}${file.separator}src${file.separator}main${file.separator}               resources${file.separator}META-INF${file.separator}persistence.xml" />
    </openjpac>
</target>
```

`

Comment: Thanks John. How can I use with my project? Where do I ned to add this?

Answer (score 1):

The JPA spec requires some type of monitoring of Entity objects, but the spec does not define how to implement this monitoring. Some JPA providers auto-generate new subclasses or proxy objects that front the user's Entity objects at runtime, while others use byte-code weaving technologies to enhance the actual Entity class objects. OpenJPA supports both mechanisms, but strongly suggests only using the byte-code weaving enhancement. The subclassing support (as provided by OpenJPA) is not recommended (and is disabled by default in OpenJPA 2.0 and beyond).(Source: http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html)

The cause of this issue is I used the subclassing support for the entity enhancement but that is disabled by default in OpenJPA2.0 and beyond.

I found the solution for this issue. We have to enhance the entity class at run time by providing a javaagent when launching the JVM that OpenJPA is going run in.

I put something like the following as a JVM argument

-javaagent:C:/OpenJPA/apache-openjpa-2.0.0/openjpa-2.0.0.jar

And I removed the bellow line from persistence.xml

```
<property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />
```

**Working persistence.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="DataSourceDemo">

        <jta-data-source>oracleDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.auditlog.model.BatchPrint</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="admin" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="test" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="defaultScheme" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```